# How to redirect existing URL to new URL?

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I want to redirect an existing URL to new URL. e.g.

```
current URL - http://localhost/blog/stltoday/
new URL - http://localhost/press/stltoday/
```

I tried URL Rewrite Management. But it is not working.

[image]

Please help

Comment: try removing the slashes at the end. Request path `blog/stltoday`, Target path `press/stltoday`.

Answer (score 2):

based on the comments....
the request path has to be filled in without the trailing slash.

- Request path `blog/stltoday`
- Target path `press/stltoday` or  `press/stltoday/`